# Optimalization of permutation

Tags: ruby

I am practicing and I got [this question](https://www.codewars.com/kata/next-bigger-number-with-the-same-digits/train/ruby):

> You have to create a function that takes a positive integer number and returns the next bigger number formed by the same digits and if no bigger number can be composed using those digits, return -1

How can I make this search faster?

```
def next_bigger(n)
  u = n.to_s.split("").permutation(n.to_s.length).to_a.map { |x| x.join("").to_i }.uniq.sort  # create sorted array of all permutations
  u.push(-1) # Add -1 to end of array
  return u[u.index(n)+1] # print next bigger or -1
end
# u is sorted array
# n is input
```

I pass test to number `"1234567980"` it is too big and it gets timeout (max is 12000ms).

Comment: Describing what the code is *supposed* to do would help your chance of actually getting an answer a lot. Especially with variable names like `u`, `n`, `x`...

Comment: Don't be lazy. Write the question. Not just link.

Comment: u,n explained x is used for array.map{|x|}

Comment: The number of permutations grows very fast with increasing number of digits. Your 10 digit number has ~3 million permutations, a 15 digit number will already have ~1 trillion. Testing every single one is pointless. Try to approach this numerically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@marmeladze thanks for help your answer makes me chose to start again
https://repl.it/Mapt/2
And this is best way to do it
!!Not mine!!
 
`def next_bigger n
  max = maxed n
  (n+1..max).each { |i| return i if max == maxed(i) }
  -1
end
def maxed n
  n.to_s.split('').sort.reverse.join.to_i
end`

Answer (score 0):

Do not convert permutation to array. It will hit memory badly.

[Array#permutation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-permutation) (if no block given) returns enumerator. You can safely walk with `.next` method on it.

```
2.4.0-rc1 :033 > b = a.chars.permutation
 => #<Enumerator: ["b", "a", "r"]:permutation> 
2.4.0-rc1 :034 > b.next
 => ["b", "a", "r"] 
2.4.0-rc1 :035 > b.next
 => ["b", "r", "a"] 
2.4.0-rc1 :036 > b.next
 => ["a", "b", "r"] 
2.4.0-rc1 :037 > b.next
 => ["a", "r", "b"] 
2.4.0-rc1 :038 > b.next
 => ["r", "b", "a"] 
2.4.0-rc1 :039 > b.next
 => ["r", "a", "b"] 
2.4.0-rc1 :040 > b.next
```

Not sure if I've read the question correctly but you can follow some approach like below.

```
def next_bigger(a)
  digits = a.to_s.chars.sort.permutation

  # ruby 2.4 provides .digits method for integers
  # but seems online interpreter version is 2.3.1
  # your can also  try this. 
  # digits =  number.to_s.split(//).map{|chr| chr.to_i}

  b = digits.next
  begin
    while a >= arr_to_int(b) do 
        b = digits.next
      end
  rescue
    return -1
  end
  return arr_to_int(b)
end

def arr_to_int arr
  arr.join.to_i
end


puts next_bigger(9)==-1
puts next_bigger(111)==-1
puts next_bigger(531)==-1
puts next_bigger(12)==21
puts next_bigger(513)==531
puts next_bigger(2017)==2071
puts next_bigger(12) == 21
puts next_bigger(414) == 441
puts next_bigger(144) ==  414
puts next_bigger(1234567890) #1234567908
```

Comment: sorry, i've forgotten to put `.sort` after `.chars`

Comment: you might add an early return for cases like `9999999999`. 
https://repl.it/M9qN
as i've said before, i am not solving problem, it is just an attempt to show you how can you go on.

you can also reduce calculations with only checking certain numbers.

Comment: Maybe I take it from bad side I will try to generate one number by comparing generated number to input I will be back when if it works

Comment: I found it.  Doesn't do permutation of the whole number, do the only permutation of last two if gets number replace it in string and send if return -1 try the last two+1  
  I will post the code when I am done.

Comment: Done I finaly made it